'openpyxl.cell._writer' module missing when I run the exe generated by pyinstaller in spyder IDE. How to make exe work?
I have following code I am using to generate exe in spyder. I have this saved as python script. Script I have works when I run from spyder.
import PyInstaller.__main__
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
'--onefile',
'--noupx',
'--hidden-import= openpyxl.cell._writer',
'AnalysisTool.py'
])

I have tried importing openpyxl but i still get the same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AnalysisTool.py", line 13, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in 
exec_module
File "openpyxl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in 
exec_module
File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in 
exec_module
File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 9, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in 
exec_module
File "openpyxl\worksheet\_write_only.py", line 13, in <module>
File "openpyxl\\worksheet\\_writer.py", line 23, in init 
openpyxl.worksheet._writer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer'
[34476] Failed to execute script 'AnalysisTool' due to unhandled 
exception!

